# Excel VBA deleting certain rows with certain conditions

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I found a code online which works but I am failing to change it for my purpose. Each entry in my spreadsheet contains different formulas as well as an `Iferror` function with the aim of making cells with error messages appear as blank. For example lets say a cell E3 is dependent on cell F3 with a certain formula (for clarification lets say F3/2.5). It is obvious if there is no entry in cell F3 then an error message would display in cell E3. For this reason, I use the `IFERROR` function to display the cell as blank. The difficulty arises when I want to delete blank rows after a click on the macro button. However, since that cell does have an entry (a formula which in turn returns an error message), that cell does not delete. Also I need to run this code over 3 different selection ranges. Please can someone help! The code I found was from a different thread on this forum and is:

```
 `sub foo()
  dim r As Range, rows As Long, i As Long
  Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z50")
  rows = r.rows.Count
    For i = rows To 1 Step (-1)
  If WorksheetFunction.CountA(r.rows(i)) = 0 Then r.rows(i).Delete
    Next
  End Sub`
```

Thanks Alot!

Comment: Can you please post your changes to the code so we can help you?

Comment: If you are just checking column E say `If Cells(i, 5).Value = "" Then r.rows(i).Delete`

Comment: @ Tim.... what if i wanted to check in a whole range?

Comment: @Rcaetano the code so far I have for that part is Dim r As Range, rows As Long, i As Long
  Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("B13:AA38")
  rows = r.rows.Count
  For i = rows To 1 Step (-1)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(r.rows(i)) = 0 Then r.rows(i).Delete
  Next

Comment: I used cell E as an example, throughout the spreadsheet I have cells depending on other cells. I just need to find a way to say if this whole row is either blank or appears blank then delete it. However, If there is even a single entry that is displayed then I do NOT want to delete it?

Comment: Does it bother you having a leading column with formula? I can do it with Sumproduct then you can delete the rows that have 0 in that column?

Comment: hi, how do you mean?

Comment: I mean another column with formula in it that counts the blank cells, then you can loop through those or use autofilter to delete the `EntireRow` where the value is 0

Comment: the problem is most of the cells do have entries inside them however I have used the IFERROR function to hide this so the cell appears to be blank? Would this still work?

Comment: Yes it will answer incoming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: If statement added to the autofilter as it was deleting a row when there were no blanks**

You will want to set up a column in the spreadsheet with the following sumproduct:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEN(A1:F1)>0)*1)
```

This is calculating how many cells' values have a length more than 0 hence are not blank, you will need to adjust cell references accordingly as I tested on a small sample of fake data.

Following this you can just loop:

```
For i = rows To 1 Step (-1)
    If Cells(i,"G") = 0 Then r.rows(i).Delete 'My formula is in column "G"
Next
```

Or set up an auto-filter and delete entire rows of the visible cells:

```
Dim lrow As Integer

If Not WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("G:G"), "0") = 0 Then
Range("A1:G1").AutoFilter
Range("A1:G1").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="0"
lrow = Cells(rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Range("G2:G" & lrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
Range("A1:G1").AutoFilter
End If
```

The only problem with using a leading column to calculate for this is if you have a lot of data coming and going as you will need to replenish the formula, though you could use auto complete in the code i guess.